# Is there a way to calculate the average of all these times (Excel 2019)?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to find the average time of all these times ([see link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTiTf.png)), but there doesn't seem to be a format that won't convert these into 12 hour time. I currently have them stored as text, so the average currently cannot be calculated. I've tried multiple h:mm:ss formats and related formats, but they all don't give an average after =AVERAGE (C2:C20). Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the values stored as text, you can get the average with

```
=AVERAGE(VALUE(C2:C21))
```

(this will have to be entered as an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) if you're using Excel 2019 or earlier)
[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed formula]

(the entries in column D are all numbers, with the custom-number format *h:mm:ss.0* applied to them)